# Bootstrap reorder multiple columns on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I've read a lot of answers but I still cannot get this to work for me.

I have 4 elements in a container-fluid. This is what they look like on desktop:
[image]

And this is what they look like on mobile:

[image]

**I need to change the order of the columns when on small (mobile) screens**. 
I need this to be the result:

[image]

This should be the order only on small screens. On desktop it should go like on picture 1: marketing, online chat, main chat, marketing 2.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="font-size: 150%;"> 
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-success"> 
    Marketing

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-danger"> 
    Online chat

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 bg-primary"> 
    Main chat

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-success"> 
    Marketing 2

    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried Bootstrap's push and pull but I cannot get it how I want. I tried:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-6 bg-success"> 
    Reklama 1

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 bg-danger"> 
    Online chat

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-2 bg-primary"> 
    Main chat

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-success"> 
    Reklama 2

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap takes a 'mobile-first' approach, so you should change your question (in your mind) to "reorder columns on larger screens". Knowing that and once defined the markup for mobile screens, the push/pull keywords would work ok in larger screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will consider that with on **small (mobile) screens** you want to say **xs** screen  size.

I really do not know if it's the best way to fix your problem, but you can try to use `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` to change the order in different devices sizes.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row hidden-xs" style="font-size: 150%;"> 

         <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-success"> 
         Marketing            
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-danger"> 
         Online chat
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 bg-primary"> 
         Main chat            
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-success"> 
         Marketing 2     
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row visible-xs" style="font-size: 150%;"> 
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 bg-primary"> 
        Main chat    
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 bg-success"> 
        Marketing
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 bg-danger"> 
        Online chat
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 bg-success"> 
        Marketing 2
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So with that, the template which the "Main chat" div appears in the top will be visible only in xs devices.

Comment: This is a good solution. I thought about using push and pull, but this gets the job done. Thanks Yago

Comment: Yeah, it gets the job done, but it isn't the best solution at all... you should be able to do this without duplicating the 4 elements...

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it solution bets way

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<div class="row"> 
      
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-success hidden-xs "> 
    Marketing
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 bg-primary visible-xs"> 
        Main chat    
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-danger hidden-xs"> 
    Online chat

    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 bg-success visible-xs"> 
        Marketing
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 bg-primary hidden-xs"> 
    Main chat

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 bg-danger visible-xs"> 
        Online chat
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-success hidden-xs"> 
    Marketing 2

    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 bg-success visible-xs"> 
        Marketing 2
        </div>
</div>
```